# os Catalina and Laravel Homestead MySql error: ERROR 2007 (HY000): Protocol mismatch; server version = 11, client version = 10

Tags: mysql, homestead, macos-catalina, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to connect to `MySQL` server within Vagrant's version of `Laravel Homestead`, which runs `MySQL 5.7`.

I never seem to had any problems with it, but on my new laptop with Catalina I'm getting the following error when trying to connect using recommended settings:

```
$ mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=33060 -uhomestead -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2007 (HY000): Protocol mismatch; server version = 11, client version = 10
```

I also tried using mysql clients (`Sequel Pro` and `Workbench`) with exactly same error message.
Anyone would be able to shine some light on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: have you found any solution to this? I have the same issue too!

Answer (score 5):

In my case, changing my host from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost` fixed it.

Comment: That's not possible. He is using the ip address specifically because he is supplying the port. If you supply `localhost` it will (at least going by what I've read) always use the socket, not TCP.

Answer (score 1):

On running homestead up, I got

Fixed port collision for 3306 => 33060. Now on port 2200.

So changed port in the mysql client config to 2200.